# private func: Missing argument for parameter #1 in call

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

Well, here's another 'Missing argument for parameter #1 in call' issue. (Seems Apple could do a better job naming its errors :-p )

In my class, I'm calling a private function `libraryVisibility()`, and on that line I get a `Missing argument for parameter #1 in call` error on compilation. Don't really understand why.

Anyhow, here's the code:

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var libraryState: Bool = libraryVisibility()

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        …
    }

    private func libraryVisibility() -> Bool {
        …
        // dostuff and return boolean
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can't call instance functions in the default initialiser of a property

You can either make your `libraryVisibility()` function a `class` function:

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var libraryState : Bool = AppDelegate.libraryVisibility()

     private class func libraryVisibility() -> Bool {
        let homeUrl = NSURL(string: NSHomeDirectory())
        let libraryUrl = NSURL(string: "Library", relativeToURL: homeUrl)

        return libraryUrl!.hidden
    }
}
```

Or you could make your `libraryState` property a `lazy` property:

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    lazy var libraryState : Bool = self.libraryVisibility()

    private func libraryVisibility() -> Bool {
        let homeUrl = NSURL(string: NSHomeDirectory())
        let libraryUrl = NSURL(string: "Library", relativeToURL: homeUrl)

        return libraryUrl!.hidden
    }
}
```

The property will then get initialised the first time you use it.

[Mike Buss has a nice usage guide on how to use `lazy` variables.](http://mikebuss.com/2014/06/22/lazy-initialization-swift/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have solved it, but not entirely sure why this is working:

Giving the `libraryState` variable a default value and setting it inside `applicationDidFinishLaunching` seems to do the trick:

```
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var libraryState: Bool = false

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {

        libraryState = libraryVisibility()

    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I can't figure out why this was the case. Anybody any ideas?

Comment: Could it be that the function is being called before the class is entirely instantiated, and that's why it is having problems with calling the function?